# Transition between two multiframe

Tags: animate

When two or more multiframe succed in an animateinlane from animate package there is a glitch between the two which result in a way smoothless animation.

I have tried a lot of alternative, find some which can work (with ifelse package in a single multiframe) but none was satisfying.

my code looks smth like this

```
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{16} 
    \multiframe{100}{rangle=0+0.01} {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % first multiframe
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \multiframe{100}{rangle=0+0.01} {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % second multiframe
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Grahn answered me on Gitlab :

> The solution to the problem of consecutive \multiframe commands is simple : Just put a \newframe in between. See the animate package manual, [section 5 "The user Interface"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#section.5), at the top of [pg. 6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#page=6) where this is documented. The same applies to more single frames to follow a \multiframe or a \multiframe to follow a single frame:

```
  ...
\newframe
  ...
\newframe
  \multiframe{...}{...}
\newframe % <== required
  \multiframe{...}{...}
\newframe
  ...
\newframe
  ...
```

Thanks to him for his work and his support.